# jQuery open modal on drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to open a modal window after dropping an element. I've searched the boards and can't find anything. Here's what I have so far, but it's not working. The item drags and drops as it should, but the modal doesn't open:

```
    $( "#table #food li.corn" ).draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                        return false;       
            }
    });
    $( "#plate ul" ).droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );   
        }
    });
    $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "slow"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `$( "#cornDialog" ).dialog( "open" );` into the `drop:` function of the droppable.

Like so:

```
$( "#plate ul" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );  
        $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
    }
});
```

EDIT: alternatively, you could implement `stop()` on the draggable:

```
$( "#table #food li.corn" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                    return false;       
        }
});
```

Comment: here's the problem though, I have a number of other draggable elements that each need to have their own dialog box upon being dropped. Should have mentioned that!

Comment: I thought about that too, but than it could trick even if someone released the drag away from the specific drop area. I need the modal to popup once it's actually dropped on the "droppable" region

Comment: In the droppable's drop function, you can look at the ui.draggable and decide which dialog to show based on that.  Maybe based on a class name?

Comment: mmm....I think I follow. Gotta a quick sample? Are you talking like and 'if' statement?

Comment: yes.  `if (ui.draggable.hasClass('someClass')) { //show dialog }`

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your dialog code in the droppable drop callback so like this

```
   $( "#table #food li.corn" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                    return false;       
        }
});
$( "#plate ul" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );  
        $( "#cornDialog" ).dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
           hide: "slow"
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks Kyle - I tried this. No firebug errors but the modal still won't open for me :(